# Running service with virtual account on Windows 8 Server

Tags: windows, service, active-directory, visual-c++-2010

My service previously run as Local System.
Now I need to run it in domain with kerberos authentication.
I configured the service to run with virtual account.
In Log On tab I changed radio button to This Account: 
  NT SERVICE\MyService

From this point my service fails on start with no logs.
The only error I found in the system log is:

```
Faulting application name: myservice.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x547d6f26
Faulting module name: myservice.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x547d6f26
Exception code: 0xc0000417
Fault offset: 0x0000000000015858
Faulting process id: 0x11bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d012335247ea86
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MyCompany\bin\myservice.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\MyCompany\bin\myservice.exe
Report Id: 90beca46-7e26-11e4-8aa5-000c298675c1
```

My service crashes on the method StartServiceCtrlDispatcher.

Maybe I do something wrong or any idea how to start an investigation?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was write permissions.
If your service writes files and you run it in context of MSA, you should grant your MSA write permissions to directories you write to.